# What affects settlement happiness?

Tags: fallout-4

I know that to keep settlers happy you need to have 1 bed, 1 food and 1 water for each of them. I also know that you need to have a defense of `food + water` to keep people safe. I saw on some of the shops that they increase happiness. I have heard rumors online that there are other factors to happiness. one of the most believable ones was that the more decorations you have the happier people are. some of the others were a little bit off, like some how if you have a lot of TVs happiness will glitch and start decreasing. I head one person saying that if a synth infiltrates your settlement they can start to decrease your happiness. Do these things actually affect your settlement happiness? If so how big is the impact? What are the other factors that will affect it?

Answer (score 0):

"Settlement happiness affects your settlers mood. If they are happier they will be more productive whether that is harvesting crops, fighting off attacks or purifying more water."

Found this at this [link](http://www.skillshotter.com/fallout-4-settlement-happiness/)

This article can explain pretty much what you need to do in order to increase happiness, that way you can understand what to do and what will affect your settlement in that matter.

Comment: You should post the key info from that link in your answer in case that link dies, your answer won't actually answer much of anything... As it stands, this isn't a very high-quality answer.